# In Dart, a function of type (int) => String can't be called with int

Tags: dart, lambda, types, type-erasure

I have the following code:

```dart
typedef Eater<T> = String Function(T value);

Eater<T> eaterFor<T>(T value) {
  // Find an appropriate eater.
  if (value is int) {
    return ((int value) => 'Eating int $value.') as Eater<T>;
  } else if (value is String) {
    return ((String value) => 'Eating String $value.') as Eater<T>;
  }
  throw 'No eater found for $value.';
}

extension on Object? {
  void eat() {
    final eater = eaterFor(this);
    print(eater(this)); // This fails.
  }
}

void main() => 4.eat();
```

I expected this to print `Eating int 4.`, but the line with `print` fails with the following message (on DartPad, probably slightly different on VM):

```
Closure 'eaterFor_closure': type '(int) => String' is not a subtype of type '(Object?) => String'
```

Apparently, the closure of type `(int) => String` can't be called with `this`, which is of type `int`.
I think this should somehow work, but apparently, my mental model of how Dart works doesn't match the compiler.

What am I missing here? We have a closure and a value that matches its input variable's type.
I know there are lots of casts and maybe-not-completely-type-safe parts, but we should be able to call the closure with the value, shouldn't we?

Here are my attempts so far, which didn't work:

- cast `eater` to `String Function(dynamic value)`
- save `this` into a temporary variable

Why exactly is the error thrown?
And how can I call the `eater` with `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics and extensions are statically determined by the compiler and not runtime. Your problem is that the following:

```
extension on Object? {
  void eat() {
    final eater = eaterFor(this);
    print(eater(this)); // This fails.
  }
}
```

Is actually compiled to the following:

```
extension on Object? {
  void eat() {
    final eater = eaterFor<Object?>(this);
    print(eater(this)); // This fails.
  }
}
```

The compiler can only guess that the type T must be `Object?` event if the type can be more precise on runtime. This has the consequence that you get:

```
Eater<Object?> eaterFor(Object? value) {
  // Find an appropriate eater.
  if (value is int) {
    return ((int value) => 'Eating int $value.') as Eater<Object?>;
  } else if (value is String) {
    return ((String value) => 'Eating String $value.') as Eater<Object?>;
  }
  throw 'No eater found for $value.';
}
```

This is not really valid since:

```
String Function(Object? value);
```

Can take a lot more types of values as input than just `int`. So your cast fails since `((int value) => 'Eating int $value.')` cannot be cast as `String Function(Object? value)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should do not additionally cast arguments

```
Eater<T> eaterFor<T>(T value) {
  // Find an appropriate eater.
  if (value is int) {
    return ((T value) => 'Eating int $value.');
  } else if (value is String) {
    return ((T value) => 'Eating String $value.');
  }
  throw 'No eater found for $value.';
}
```

Comment: And this will actually works since we then will return e.g. `((Object? value) => 'Eating int $value.');` if we use this code in the example provided in the question (since the generic T will be determined by the compiler to be `Object?`)